# Setting the position of a tool tip for dynamic elements using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

So I have the following code:

```
$(document).tooltip
({
    tooltipClass: 'customToolTipTop',
    position: {my: 'center bottom', at: 'center top-10'},        
    content: function() 
    {
        var title = $(this).attr("title");

        if (title != null)
        {
            title = title.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), "<br />");
        }
        return title;
    }        
});
```

So this sets the tooltips for all elements to have the class custom tooltip and be above the centre of the element. This works fine.
I also have css that shows an Arrow that points to the element.

My problem is that I have to specify the position and so the css class. So if the element is near the top of the page the tooltip will show under it but the arrow will still point down.

Is there a way I can know where the tooltip will show in relation to the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add some code in the tooltip's [`open`](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-open) event (at which point the tooltip will be ready for measuring) to see whether the `offset().top` of the element is higher or lower than the `offset().top` of the tooltip.  Something like this (where `elem` is whatever triggered the tooltip):

```
open: function(e,ui){
    var topOfToolTip = ui.tooltip.offset().top;
    if (elem.offset().top < topOfToolTip) {
        // Add a class or whatever
        ui.tooltip.addClass("top");
    }
}
```

See this [fiddle where it's all put together](https://jsfiddle.net/k1r91mck/1/).  I'm likely "cheating" to produce that `elem` variable in the fiddle.  There's probably a canonical way to get the element that triggered the tooltip, but I'm rusty.